# How to terminate cat command within a shell script

Tags: shell-script, cat, exit, tr

I wrote a `shell script` that uses `cat` and `tr` commands to generate a file. My shell script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "generating random file > plaintext \n"
cat -v | tr "a-z" "b-y" < plaintext  > generatedtext
```

On executing the script, it doesn't terminate the `cat` command and when I've `CTRL` + `Z` to stop the shell script execution. Now, when I look into the contents of the `generatedtext` - the first character is altered(based on `tr`) and the rest of the characters are all one and the same as in the plaintext.

For example, if the contents of `plaintext`

> This is an apple.

After shell execution, the contents of `generatedtext`

> xhis is an apple.

Comment: If you don't have any control chars then `cat` is useless..

Comment: Your `tr` ranges are dissimilar: `a-z` is 26 characters, `b-y` is 24. Is that intentional? (Your input text characters x, y, and z will all end up as y.)

Comment: @roaima yes it was intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `tr` after you read the plaintext file:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "generating random file > plaintext \n"
cat -v < plaintext | tr "a-z" "b-y" > generatedtext
```

In your question `plaintext` is redirected to `tr` not `cat`. 
Alternatively, you can run the piped commands in a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "generating random file > plaintext \n"
( cat -v | tr "a-z" "b-y" ) < plaintext  > generatedtext
```

Comment: it worked when I executed as a shell command. But when I placed it in a shell script(inside the program.sh file) it just replaces the first character

Comment: @GIRI which version of bash are you using? which OS? It works for me when invoked within a shell script. Does the script not exit until you press CTRL+Z ?

Comment: @GIRI, just realized, by any chance do you have the case mixed up ? `tr "A-Z" "B-Y"` ? That could explain why only the first letter is replaced.

Comment: I'm on OS X, script exits without ctrl+Z(tr after plaintext). bash version is 3.2.57

Comment: ya that i was the issue. case mixed up my input file has the uppercase start character.